# Concatenating csv files with different, empty and duplicated headers

Tags: python, csv, concatenation

I have in input several csv files, each one with hundreds of columns and thousands of rows, that I need to concatenate.
These files have in common most of the columns headers, but not all, further each file has some columns with no headers at all, and last (but not least!) there can be duplicated headers (obviously not known a priori).

The strategy I thought to use is the following:

1- read initially only the headers of each csv file, and find the common ones

2- concatenate the files by using those common headers

I have accomplished the first point, but I'm stuck in the second.

Let's consider the following data as for csv input files:

**csv_1**:
[image: csv file number 1]

**csv_2**:
[image: csv file number 2]

**csv_3**:
[image: csv file number 3]

Here I just report the list of headers for each file:

```
['A', 'B', '70', 'C', '690', '', '', '0', '1', '3', '5', 'D']
['A', 'B', '5', 'C', '690', '', '', '0', '1', '3', '5', 'D']
['A', 'B', '3', 'C', '690', '', '', '0', '1', '3', '5', 'D']
```

So, you can see that in each csv files there are two columns (the sixth and the seventh) with no headers. The second file has the header '5' duplicated, while in the third file the duplicated header is '3'.

What I need to exactly have is the following dataframe structure:
[image: the three csv files concatenated]

Here there are no duplicated columns and the not-common columns are not present anymore. Additionally, there are other two columns: 'file' reporting to which file that row belongs to (i.e. one=csv_1, two=csv_2, three=csv_3, where 'one', 'two' and 'three' are nicknames I define initially and that are available in a list called file_nickname), and 'count' reporting the corresponding number of row for each file

Said this, I have started with a list called 'filenames' containing the files. To get the headers for each file I have used the following:

```
import csv

headers_list = []
for file in filenames:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        d_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        headers_list.append(d_reader.fieldnames)
```

Please, note that I cannot use Pandas read_csv (`headers_list = [pd.read_csv(file, engine="python", index_col=0, nrows=0).columns.tolist() for file in filenames]`) because when reading in this way I would get duplicated columns specified as 'x.1', and the option mangle_dupe_cols has never been implemented and deprecated since version 1.5.0.

Given the headers_list, the list of common headers can be obtained by using the following:

```
headers_common = list(set(headers_list[0]).intersection(*headers_list[1:]))
```

I can even get the list of not common header (may be useful) with the following two lines:

```
headers_list_joined = list(set([item for l in headers_list for item in l]))
headers_not_in_common = [i for i in headers_list_joined if i not in headers_common]
```

To concatenate the files, if there were no duplicated columns I could use the following one-line:

```
result = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(file, engine="python", skiprows= 0, usecols=lambda x: x not in headers_not_in_common) 
     for file in filenames], keys=file_nickname, names=['file', 'count'])
```

but, for the same reason as before, Pandas cannot be used.

Thus I have used the following lines:

```
with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
        csv_write_file = csv.writer(output)
        for file in filenames:
            with open(file, newline='') as f:
                for row in csv.reader(f):
                    #row.append(file)
                    csv_write_file.writerow(row)
```

In this way I get the three files concatenated without duplicated columns, but:

1- there are the not common columns

2- the header is repeated each time

3- I don't know how to obtain the columns 'file' and 'count' (well, by using the line row.append(file) I can get the name of the csv file, but instead I need the nickname).

I hope that my question is quite clear, thanks for any suggestion.

EDIT: I have tried to explain better where I'm stuck (points 1 to 3)

Comment: "Please, note that I cannot use Pandas read_csv ... because when reading in this way I would get duplicated columns specified as 'x.1'" - definitely better to read using pandas and then just change the columns to be what you want after the fact. `df.rename(columns={"x.1": "my_custom_col_name"})` works fine. also, please reduce the scope of this question if you want help. *where exactly are you stuck?* if you need help performing a single task in pandas, we can help you. but as it stands, this has multiple complex questions in one.

Comment: Dataframes seem like they would provide such a cleaner route for this logic. As you move through each file, you can see what columns already exist in the final `df`, add new columns from the file to the final `df` and then do a `concat`, rinse and repeat. Sure, you'll still have edge cases like duplicate column names, but that seems easier to solve with this approach as well. Your current implementation has you tied up in knots.

Comment: The headers are duplicated but the data under them are not, so you are throwing away data. Is that what you want? It looks like `70`(file1) -->  `3`(first instance file2) --> `5`(first instance file3).

Comment: Will you please edit your post and change the images to textual examples?

Comment: @Michael Delgado: I cannot know a priori the name of the duplicated column (it changes from a csv to another), and above all I don't want the first instance, instead I need the second (the one that would be named x.1)
@ JNevill: sorry, I have not understood your suggestion
@ Adrian Klaver: yes, I don't care the data of the first instance
@ Zach Young: I tried initially, but it was very very confusing, so I opted for images

Comment: I definitely disagree with your reasoning @heartbit - it’s easy to find all columns with the name ending in `.1` and then do something with the pair of duplicates. It’s at least as easy as manually handling this when reading it in with the csv module - I’d argue it’s much, much easier.

Comment: Dear Michael Delgado, maybe it's easier to understand what I mean if you try to run result=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, engine="python", skiprows= 0, usecols=lambda x: x not in headers_not_in_common) for file in filenames], keys=file_nickname, names=['file','count']): not only you get the two duplicated columns 3.1 and 5.1 (containing data I need), but they are also a mixing of the two pristine columns '3' (first instance) and '3' (second instance). That's why I'm trying with the csv module. I guess it would be very useful an option like mangle_dupe_cols in Pandas. Anyway any hint is welcome!

Comment: @Michael Delgado, the question could be the following: if you have a cvs file with duplicated headers, and you want to read it by using Pandas, is there a way to avoid renaming headers with x.1, x.2 and so on? Or in other words: I just want each header without being renamed, just like the csv module does that by its own.

Comment: no, you have the problem either way. with the csv module, you are maintaining the positional order, and need to manually decide how to handle each conflict. if you used pandas, you'd be working file-wise. for each file, read it in, then align the columns with your intended output format, then concatenate all the files. yes, you will have to do some cleaning on the resulting dataframes. no, this is not an insurmountable hurdle. but I see them as separable problems. csv parsing is something pandas does very, very well. you have a data cleaning problem regardless.

Comment: essentially, I'm saying "don't do this": `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(...) for f in ...]).` instead, build a list of dataframes by iterating over the files. then, clean and align the headers. then concatenate.

Comment: the main problem with your q is that you have a giant messy workflow problem, not a programming question. we can help with targeted questions; "read in three large files and dedupe the columns and align the data and concatenate them and can you also debug my csv parser" is not a single question. you need to step through your workflow and identify the issues. if there's something you don't understand, feel free to ask a new question. we're advising you to use pandas to take the complexity out of parsing the csvs. you don't have to take our advice, but this question is still too broad.